# How do I update the iOS simulator to the latest iOS 11 beta?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9-beta

I have downloaded Xcode 9 beta 5, in order to debug a problem with our app on iOS 11 beta. Xcode beta 5 comes with iOS simulator 11.0 beta 5.

Now, Apple has released iOS 11.0 beta 6, but they have not released a new beta version of Xcode.

How do I update the simulator to beta 6?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Sometimes beta updates are released to devices only.

Comment: You might very well be right. Are you taking this just from your own experience (which is fine), or could you possibly link to a source?

Comment: He's an engineer that works on the sim.  He is a source.  Xcode did not release a beta concurrently with iOS 11 beta 6.  Xcode 9 beta 6 was released concurrently with iOS 11 beta 7 (which it contained).  There was no public release of iOS 11 beta 6 for the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Simulator sometimes updates with the beta versions of Xcode.

You can check it by comparing build of latest beta on [developer portal (beta software - download)](https://developer.apple.com/download/#ios-restore-images-iphone-new) with build of simulator in `Devices and Simulators` window of xcode

[image]

---

[image]